# Closed form for $H(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty H(n-k, j)j^k$ where $H(1,k)=\frac{1}{k!}$

Tags: continuity, power-series, exponential-function, tetration, bell-numbers

Let $H(n,k)$ be defined such that
$$H(1,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\text{, and }H(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty H(n-1,j)j^k$$

As pointed out in the comments, I should mention that we must define $0^0=1$ as well, to be absolutely formal about $H(n,0)$ (to fit the properties outlined in the *motivation* section below).

**Question:**

> Does there exist a reasonably "closed-form" for $H(n,k)$, particularly one which admits a natural extension over $\mathbb{R}$?

By this definition, the computational complexity (of the partial sums) grows by the power of $n$ as $n$ increases, so this isn't even numerically that feasible.

**Motivation:** It is not to hard to show that
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty H(1,k) x^k&=e^x,\\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty H(2,k) x^k&=e^{e^x},\\
\text{and in general, }\sum_{k=0}^\infty H(n,k) x^k&=e^{⋰^x}\}^{{}_n}
\end{align*}$$

These are very much related to [bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) (in fact $eB_k=H(2,k)k!$). There seems to be hint of some "closed form" for $H(3,k)$ as well, as $H(3,0)=e^e$ and $H(3,1)=e^{e+1}$, however other than those I see no other nice values.

---

**My work:** Of course, by means of the Gamma function, one can extend $H(n,k)$ over $k\in\mathbb{R}$, however extending over $n\in\mathbb{R}$ is rather difficult, due to the inductive nature of their definition.

However, it is clear from [playing around with the partial terms](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/utm58u7fbk) that they almost provide an interpolation for us.

For instance, if we consider the sum
$$\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^J \frac{j^k}{j!},$$
(which is precisely the partial sums of $H(2,k)$), notice that when $J=1$ this sum is precisely $H(1,k)$. Hence, intuitively as $J$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$, we interpolate (albeit discretely) between $H(1,k)$ and $H(2,k)$. We can convert this into a continuous interpolation $J\mapsto x$ by the taking the limit
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{J\to\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^J \frac{j^k}{j!} - \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^J \frac{(j+1+x)^k}{(j+1+x)!} &= \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{j^k}{j!} - \frac{(j+1+x)^k}{(j+1+x)!}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Thus given some monotone bijection $\phi:[1,2)\mapsto [1,\infty)$, we can guess
$$x\in[1,2)\implies H(x,k)\approx\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{j^k}{j!} - \frac{(j+1+\phi(x))^k}{(j+1+\phi(x))!}\right),$$
which is a good start, but seems rather contrived and arbitrary. I'm really just hoping that we get a natural extension over $\mathbb{R}$ for free by finding a more "closed-form" solution for $H$.

Comment: Interesting problem and (+1). How do you definece $ \left[n-1 \atop j\right]$ for $j=0$ ?  If I may suggest, it could be clearer if you use "normal" notations everywhere. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you. I will make an edit to change $\left[n \atop k\right]$ to $H(n,k)$. In the case that $0^0$ occurs, I define $0^0=1$. Er... well, whatever allows them to satisfy being the coefficients for the power series of iterated exponentiation (as shown in the motivation). I think that means setting $0^0=1$, but I'll have to double-check before I clarify in my edit.

Comment: @Graviton You can get an $n-1$  series expansion for $H(n,k)$ by evaluating $H(n,k)=\frac1{k!}\left.\frac{d^k}{dx^k}e^{\dots^x}\right|_0$ using [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/20/02/0002/) or expanding $e^y$ as a series. Would you like this explicit multiple series as an answer?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Intriguing! I would very much appreciate such an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maclaurin series gives:
$$H(n,k)=\frac1{k!}\left.\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\underbrace{e^{\dots^ x}}_{n\ “e”\text s}\right|_0$$

Repeated application of a [Stirling S2 formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/20/02/0002/):

> $$\frac{d^jf(e^x)}{dx^j}=\sum_{m=1}^j e^{jx}s_j^{(m)}f^{(j)}(e^x)$$

gives:

$$k!H(5,k)=e^{e^{e^e}}\sum_{k_1=1}^k \sum_{k_2=1}^k \sum_{k_3=1}^k \sum_{k_4=1}^k s_k^{(k_1)}s_{k_1}^{(k_2)} s_{k_2}^{(k_3)} s_{k_3}^{(k_4)} e^{k_1}e^{k_2e}e^{k_3 e^e}$$

which [is true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+%7Blim%5BD%5Be%5Ee%5Ee%5Ee%5Ee%5Ex%2C%7Bx%2C4%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E0%5D%2C+e%5Ee%5Ee%5Ee+sum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5Bsum%5Bstirlings2%284%2Cu%29+e%5Ev+stirlings2%28u%2Cv%29+e%5E%28w+e%29+stirlings2%28v%2Cw%29+stirlings2%28w%2Cy%29+e%5E%28y+e%5Ee%29%2C%7By%2C1%2C4%7D%5D%2C%7Bw%2C1%2C4%7D%5D%2C%7Bv%2C1%2C4%7D%5D%2C%7Bu%2C1%2C4%7D%5D%7D). So, the closed form is:

$$\bbox[border: 2pt solid gray]{H(n,k)=\frac 1{k!}\underbrace{e^{\dots^e}}_{n-1\ “e”\text s}\sum_{k_{1,\dots,n-1}=1}^ks_k^{(k_1)}\prod_{j=1}^{n-2}s_{k_j}^{(k_{j+1})}e^{k_j\underbrace{e^{\dots^e}}_{j-1\ “e”\text s}}}$$

For $n=1,2$, assume an [empty product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) and for $n=1$, the sum evaluates to $1$. This formula matches the special cases in the OP’s question